# jquery Ui price Slider cookie

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

im having dificulties of integrating cookie support (not so good with it) for the fallowing price slider

Here is the code for the js

```
$(window).load(function(){
function showProducts(minPrice, maxPrice) {
    $("#products li").hide().filter(function() {
        var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
        return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
    }).show();
}

$(function() {
    var options = {
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [50, 300],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var min = ui.values[0],
                max = ui.values[1];

            $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);
            showProducts(min, max);
        }
    }, min, max;

    $("#slider-range").slider(options);

    min = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
    max = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);

    $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);

    showProducts(min, max);
});​
});
```

and the html

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<div class="demo">

    <p>
        <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
    </p>

    <div id="slider-range"></div>
    <ul id="products">
            <li data-price="10"> product - £10 </li>
            <li data-price="50"> product - £50 </li>
            <li data-price="100"> product - £100 </li>
            <li data-price="150"> product - £150 </li>
            <li data-price="200"> product - £200 </li>
        </ul>
    </div
```

​

Here is link to my jsfindle [Price slider](http://jsfiddle.net/nSJAS/)

it uses jquery 1.72

My question is how to put cookie support to it, so when visitor selects something it will save his selection and when he refreshes the page or comes back to the page it will still include his selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work with cookies

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nSJAS/38/

**JS codes:**

```
//COOKIE code from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie
var allCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return null; }
    return unescape(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|.*;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*((?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?).*"), "$1"));
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toGMTString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=" + escape(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return; }
    document.cookie = escape(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: /* optional method: you can safely remove it! */ function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nIdx = 0; nIdx < aKeys.length; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = unescape(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};

function showProducts(minPrice, maxPrice) {
    $("#products li").hide().filter(function() {
        var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
        return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
    }).show();
}

var min_value = parseInt(allCookies.getItem("cookie_min_val"), 10);
min_value = (min_value > 0) ? min_value : 0;

var max_value = parseInt(allCookies.getItem("cookie_max_val"), 10);
max_value = (max_value > 0) ? max_value : 0;
//alert(cookie_val);
$(function() {

    var options = {
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 300,
        values: [min_value?min_value:50, max_value?max_value:300],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var min = ui.values[0],
                max = ui.values[1];

            $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);
            allCookies.setItem("cookie_min_val", min, "", "/");
            allCookies.setItem("cookie_max_val", max, "", "/");
            showProducts(min, max);
        }
    }, min, max;

    $("#slider-range").slider(options);

    if(min_value>0){
        min = min_value;
        max = max_value;
    }else{
        min = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
        max = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
    }

    $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);

    showProducts(min, max);
});​
```

Comment: tried this but it doesnt save both values, for example if i select front selector at 159 and end one at 250, and then refresh it shows at 250 till 300. Is it posible to fix this to save both values ? start and end ?

Comment: anyone else to help with this problem ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I added cookies only for `min` value. Now I added for `max` value too. Updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

to add support for cookies in jQuery just follow this tutorial:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

This js needs "to be installed" as a jQuery standard plugin (so just include the js file in your page), and you'll be able to write and read cookies where you saved your shop list.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [plugin for jQuery called ***$.cookie()***](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Then you can do something like:

```
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var min = ui.values[0],
            max = ui.values[1];

        $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);

        $.cookie('the_cookie', { min: min, max: max });

        showProducts(min, max);
    }
```

Comment: tried with this but sliders are not movable graphicaly, and somehow it doesnt work

Comment: did you properly add the cookie plguin below the jquery script link?

Comment: here is the jquery script added but still it doesnt work.
http://jsfiddle.net/nSJAS/16/